# Rails 4 Role Managment for SaaS based Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, session, database-design, session-cookies

I have the following structure in my application which is a SaaS based app.

```
User hasMany Companies
Company hasMany Projects
Project hasMany Users
```

**Database Structure**

```
users(id, name, email, password, ....)
companies(id, name, ..., created_by)
company_members(id, company_id, user_id, is_admin)
events(id, name, company_id, created_by)
event_members(id, company_id, event_id, user_id, is_admin)
```

At any given time like the Facebook Account switching from User to Pages a User in the Application can only see content related to one Company. So i need to save an instance which company is he working on and remember it to log him into the same the next time he logs in.

Also i need to persistently save that the user is fetching content related to that particular company alone.

**Now lets consider Users - A,B,C,D**

```
Company X has A,B,D as its members - (Admin for the company - A)
Company Y has A,B,C,D as its members - (Admin for the company - B,D)
===========
Company X has Project X1, X2
Project X1 has A,D as its members (project manager for the project is D)
Project X2 has A,B,D as its members (project manager for the project is A)
===========
Company Y has Project Y1, Y2
Project Y1 has A,B,D as its members (project manager for the project is B)
Project Y2 has A,B,C,D as its members (project manager for the project is A,B)
```

**Problem**

I am okay with the database design of the application but i am trying to figure out how to Put in place the Authorization and Role Management to handle 3 level of different roles. A User can be a Normal Member of the Company but can be a project manager for a particular project he is a part of. But in another project he is just a project member. The same User can be another Company owner etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider you have 3 job levels
RoleID 1- Projmanager
RoleID 2- Proj_Member
You could keep a seperate table called User access table, schema 
Tbl_Role_Manager: RoleID, RoleDefined
TBl_Proj_Details: ProjID, ProjName
Tbl_User_Access: Userid, Username, User_Role_ID, Proj_Code_ID
By this way you can always do a round of check on these table before you display the contents of the page.

For ex:
Depending on the user_Role handle in the code or the procedure and display the page
Select User_role from 
Tbl_User_Access T, TBl_Proj_Details V,Tbl_Role_Manager R
where V.ProjID=T.Proj_Code_ID
 and R.RoleID=V.User_Role_ID